# How to pass multiple pipeline parameters as user input to an external program powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters, user-input, pipeline

I'm trying to find a way to automate a multi input license activation with PowerShell. I am able to launch an external program with the initial input variable `$aActiationResponse` accepted successfully but I'm not sure how to pass addtional parameters to the external program in a sequential order after this.

```psh
$ActivationResponse ='2'
$ActivationResponse |
  & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MicroStrategy\JRE\160_38\Win64\bin\java' `
    -jar 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MicroStrategy\MALicMgr.jar' `
    -console
```

Here is the workflow I've been able to automate:

> ****************************************************************** 
> MicroStrategy License Manager (console mode).
>
> The console mode can be used to run an audit, activate and deactivate
>   your MicroStrategy software installation.
>
> ---
>
> Activation status of your MicroStrategy installation: INACTIVE
>
> Please select from the following options:
>   1. Perform Audit
>   2. Generate Activation File and Request Activation Code
>   3. Server Activation using Activation Code
>   0. Exit the console mode Please enter what you would like to do:  2
>
> ****************************************************************** 
> MicroStrategy Software Activation.
>
> Installation Information (All fields are required)
>
> Use !q any time to exit
>
> As part of the Server Activation process it is required that you
>   provide information about the characteristics of the Server
>   Installation.
>
> Installation Name: [] : TechSupport1 Installation Location: [] :
>   McLean, VA
>   1. Production
>   2. Development
>   3. Testing
>   4. Training
>   5. Other Installation Use: [] : 3

Comment: I'm not sure how to pass the additional user input "Install Information" in the pipeline. Tried an array.

Comment: You could send a hashtable and use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx)?